# I want to format a date into a string, but its giving me nil, i want to use the date in a UITextField.text

Tags: swift

// the creationdate is coming from an api call

```
    var creationDate = "2020-11-04T16:46:59.439212Z" 

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .long
    formatter.timeStyle = .none
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    var creationDateFormattedInToDate = formatter.date(from: 
                                        creationDate)

    print("date \(creationDateFormattedInToDate)")
```

So i want that date in the format 04-11-2020 and pass in a UITextField.text

Comment: The format `"dd-MM-yyyy"` doesn’t match the string `"2020-11-04T16:46:59.439212Z"`. Not even close.

Answer (score 2):

You will need two formatters, one to parse the input date to a Date object and one to convert the date object to a string of the right format.

The input date seems to be a variant of a internet date/time so we use a ISO8601DateFormatter

```
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
formatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]
```

The second formatter is a basic DateFormatter with a custom format

```
let outputFormatter = DateFormatter()
outputFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
```

And then we can use them like this

```
if let date = formatter.date(from: creationDate) {
    someTextField.text = outputFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I got fooled by auto-completion in Xcode to believe I couldn't write just .withFractionalSeconds but trying again after a restart it works fine (I am on a beta version :)). Good to know about the lost precision but I guess in this case it is not so relevant.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson You would loose precision with DateFormatter as well but it will add 000 to fill the gap

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use one formatter for parsing the response from the server (which is in what’s called and “ISO 8601” or “RFC 3339” format), and another for preparing the string representation of the date in the UI.

Regarding the date formatter for parsing the server response:

- Set the formatter’s `locale` to `Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")`.
- The setting of the styles when parsing this date string are irrelevant if you’re going to set `dateFormat`.
- When parsing the date from the string, set `dateFormat` to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX`.
- If you ever plan on using this formatter for the reverse date-to-string conversion (for preparing date strings to be sent to the server) you might want to set the `timeZone` of the formatter to `TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)`.

Regarding the date formatter used to prepare the string representation of the date in your UI:

- I would not advise ever using a fixed `dd-MM-yyyy` format in your UI. That might be natural for European users, but it may be unnatural to most US users, who generally expect to see month before the day.
- I would suggest not using `dateFormat` for this second date formatter, but rather using a `dateStyle` (e.g. of `.medium` or `.long`). It results in a nice, localized, and natural reading date string.
- If you insist in using `dd` and `MM` and `yyyy` in your UI, I’d localize it with `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate` so that the day and the month appear in the logical order that this particular user would expect (month-followed-by-day for US users, day-followed-by-month for most other locales).

Thus:

```
let serverDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
serverDateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
serverDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
serverDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX"

let uiFormatter = DateFormatter()
uiFormatter.dateStyle = .medium  // or uiFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("ddMMyyyy")

if let date = serverDateFormatter.date(from: creationDateString) {
    let string = uiFormatter.string(from: date)
    // use that `string` in your UI
}
```

Comment: You just need a single `S` it will parse as many fractional seconds as available (limited to 3). The only difference is when creating a date string. If you add more than 3 SSS it will fill it with zeros.

Comment: I wonder why they did not add an option to specify the precision of the fractional seconds with ISO8601DateFormatter. It probably uses DateFormatter under the hood otherwise they wouldn’t have it fixed to 3 digits.

Comment: If I might possibly use the formatter for doing the reverse conversion, I like to specify the desired number of millisecond digits, in case the server is particular about the format. (That’s why I didn’t use `ISO8601DateFormatter`.) It might not be an issue here, but seems like best practice, IMHO. But to each his own.